# Is it possible to add one Spring context to another?

Tags: java, spring

I have two contexts:

```
ApplicationContext context1 = ...
ApplicationContext context2 = ...
```

And I want to add `context2` to `context1`. Is it possible? I mean to do that programmatically.

Comment: why you want to do that ?

Comment: I just want to try to merge two contexts.

Comment: It is not possible for example because of beans id conflict. Please describe your problem, I am sure it can be resolved different way.

Answer (score 0):

No idea why are you doing it by this:

```
ApplicationContext context1 = ...
ApplicationContext context2 = ...
```

Above option will create two independent spring IoC containers. And as @Konrad said you cant merge in that way.

What you can if you have a lot of spring context files is:

```
    String[] contextFiles = {"/firstContextFile.xml",
                             "/secondContextFile.xml",
                             "/thirdContextFile.xml"};
    ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(contextFiles);
```

Or

You can add another spring resource in `firstContextFile.xml` with:

```
<import resource="classpath:secondContextFile.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:thirdContextFile.xml" />
```

and just load spring context with this:

```
    ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/firstContextFile.xml");
```